# How to make a voice assistant android apk offline?

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, voice

I want to make an android project that can understand my voice command and can response with voice.So, are there some api or frameworks? If not, how do I analyse and translate that voice?

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is probably not the right place to ask for an advice, but let me answer you. [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) is probably the most popular free speach recognition library, working offline. I haven't used it, but I hope it's going to help you. Then you need also text-to-speach library working offline, so take a look at this catalog - https://android-arsenal.com/tag/100 . If you don't find a library, you can have the code of an open source project like [Android Mary TTS](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4514) and reuse whatever is necessary.